# Data Type for numpy.rand.seed()

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to input a seed runtime through command line option, hence wanted to understand what is the data type of numpy.rand.seed()

Comment: Just give it an integer.  The command line value will be a string, so convert it to an integer first. eg. `np.random.seed(int('100101'))` works.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html it must be an integer or an 1-d array of integers convertible to an unsigned 32-bit integer. So you should be fine with any kind of integer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [numpy docs on `np.random.seed()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html):

```
seed : int or 1-d array_like, optional
    Seed for RandomState. Must be convertible to 32 bit unsigned integers.
```

Note the error message you get when you try to use some object like a string:

```
In [5]: np.random.seed('1234')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.seed()

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d50c476bf3fe> in <module>
----> 1 np.random.seed('1234')

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.seed()

TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('<U4') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

So you must pass an object that can be converted with the "safe" casting. As far as I can tell, an easy way to check is with `np.can_cast(o, np.uint32)` (docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html)); anything returning `True` here will be useable. What is actually checked, however, can be seen in the source code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/497a00e914bfb98c0093354390f14d3843a33daa/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L689) where it converts the input object into an array of type `np.int64` with safe casting, and then checks that the object is 1-d and that the values are between 0 and 2^32 - 1, before getting cast to an unsigned long for use in the numpy C library.

So a one-liner description might be: anything "safe cast-able to a 1-d `int64` array where values end up between 0 and 2^32 - 1 after casting" can be passed into `np.random.seed()`.